# Using CuPy/cuDF, remove elements that are not distant enough to their previous elements from a sorted list

Tags: gpu, cupy, cudf

[The purpose of the code is similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665007/remove-elements-in-a-list-if-difference-with-previous-element-less-than-value)

I have a code that runs on CPUs:

```py
import pandas as pd


def remove(s: pd.Series, thres:int):
    pivot = -float("inf")
    new_s = []
    for e in s:
        if (e-pivot)>thres:
            new_s.append(e)
            pivot=e
    return pd.Series(new_s)

# s is an ascending sequence
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,4,6,9])
remove(s, thres=3)
# Out:
# 0    0
# 1    4
# 2    9
# dtype: int64
```

The input is an ascending sequence with integer values. 
This function simply removes those points `s[i]` where `d(s[i], s[i-1]) < thres`

My problem is that CuPy/cuDF do not support loops, so I can't use GPUs to accelerate the code. I only have options like `cumsum`, `diff`, and `mod` that don't fit my needs.

Is there a function like [`scan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan) in `tensorflow`?

The `remove` function can be reformulated in a form that is similar to [prefix sum (scan)](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-vi-gpu-computing/chapter-39-parallel-prefix-sum-scan-cuda):

For a sequence `[a1, a2, a3]`, the output should be `[a1, a1⨁a2, (a1⨁a2)⨁a3]`, and `⨁` is equal to

```py
⨁=lambda x,y: x if (y-x)>thres else y
```

Then `set(output)` is what I want.

Note that `(a1⨁a2)⨁a3 != a1⨁(a2⨁a3)`, in the absence of associative property, parallel computation might not be feasible.

**Update**

I found that there is already a function called [Inclusive Scan](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_scan.html#a16d7bc049ba8985dd89b10b3bcf0a8a3), all I need is a python wrapper.

Or is there any other way?